# Issue adding new columns to dataframe using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

Say I run this

```py
DF1.withColumn("Is_elite",
               array_intersect(DF1.year,DF1.elite_years))
    .show()
```

I get the result I want which is a new column called `Is_elite` with the correct values and all
Then in the next command I run

```py
DF1.show
```

It just shows me what `DF1` would have looked like had I not run the first command, my column is missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have added .show() method in the line, it is not returning a new data frame. Make the following changes and try it out

```
elite_df = DF1.withColumn("Is_elite",array_intersect(DF1.year,DF1.elite_years))
elite_df.show()
```

In case you get confused about the object in python, try to print the type of object.

```
#the following must return a dataframe object. 
print(type(elite_df))
```

Dataframes are immutable and every transformation create a new dataframe reference and hence if you try to print the old datagram, you will not get the revised result.